# Binary Search problem - Help - Trying for hours

Tags: java, binary-search

I hope you do not mind me posting this up.

I have a problem, and I have been looking at other examples of code from StackOverflow and I still cannot key the correct location on the value I am looking for.

I am to:

//Description: Performs a strong text binary search on an array for a specified value
//Parameters: int array of values and int key which item to be searched
//Returns: int indicating the first location of the item, or -1 in the case
//the key is not found.

It would be greatly appreciated if the simplest and most efficient way of doing this can be solved. Thank you in advance!

My code so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BinarySearching

{
public static int binarySearch(int[] array, int key)
{

  int begin = 0;
  int last = array.length -1;
  int mid =0;

  while (begin <= last)
  {
     mid = (begin + last) / 2;

     // Check if key is present at mid
     if (array[mid] < key)
     {
        begin = mid +1;
     }

     // If key greater, ignore left half
     else if (array[mid] > key)
     {
        last = mid - 1;
     }
        // If x is smaller, ignore right half
     else
     {
        return mid;
     }
  }

  // if we reach here, then element was
  // not present

  if(last == 0)
  {
     return -1;
  }

  return mid;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

  int[] numbers = readArrayFromFile("practice_data.txt");


  int key = 3555318 ;

  int result = binarySearch(numbers, key);

  if (result == -1)
  {
     System.out.println("Element not present " +result);
  }
  else
  {
     System.out.println("Element found at "
           + "index " + result);
  }

}//main
}//class
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Sample of text file. This would on my intellj be going to the next line after each number is entered.

Example:
1
2
3
4

Sample from Text file:

10000
-6335552
2276239
-9496279
-2570465
-3131620
6185632
6080225
-8641474
802221
4654808
-6425849
1001941
-1884575
3555318
3555318
3555318
2280363
-5578898
-1843525
2106946
1142271
5735601
6551052
-1367885
3972930
-5147855
6901888
9999313
-443147
5700530
9439329
-4407250
8461347

Comment: For what input does it not work?

Comment: in the file text, I am reading from the location of 3555318 is at location: 15, 16, & 17. When I run this code it says the location was found at 6775 in from the file text I am withdrawing the information from. At location 6775 is: -1338516

Comment: Yes! Will do not but it is very long just so you know and thank you in advance. I just double checked it is 90000 numbers long.

Comment: the post only accepts a maximum limit of 30,000

Comment: okay, thank you. I will do it now!

Comment: Is the file sorted? or is it in random order. That might be one issue as well

Comment: The file is sorted.        int ncomps = 0, nswaps= 0; // Declare and initalise counters

      for(int out = array.length-1; out > 0; out--)
      {
         for(int in = 0; in < out; in++)
         {
            ncomps++; // increment number of compariaions

            if(array[in] > array[in +1])
            {
               nswaps++;
               swap(array, in, in+1);
            }
         }
      }

Comment: Maybe I am doing this wrong?

Comment: NEVERMIND! I got it solved! Thank you Abra and Iota.